# When $X_t = {W_t}^n - k\int^{t}_{0} {W_s}^{n-2} \, ds$ is a martingale?

Tags: martingales

I know that  $X_t = {W_t}^3 - 3\int^{t}_{0} W_s \, ds$ is a martingale, but my general question is:
for what values of $k$, $X_t = {W_t}^n - k\int^{t}_{0} {W_s}^{n-2} \, ds$ is a martingale?

Comment: Itô formula allows you to answer this question.

Comment: @Surb, how can I use ito for this question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You wish to find a function $f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $$X_t=\int_0^t f(W_s)\,\mathrm d W_s=W_t^n-k\int_0^t W_s^{n-2}\,\mathrm d s.$$

According to Itô formula
$$\int_0^tf(W_s)\,\mathrm d W_s=f(W_t)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(W_s)\,\mathrm d s.$$
I let you conclude.